# DELETE from table1 the matching rows that are in table2 (no primary key in table1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table1:

| StudentId (nvarchar(50)) | Score (int) |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 56 |
| def | 34 |
| abc | 95 |

Table2:

| MemberId (nvarchar(50), no duplicates) | ComputerId (nvarchar(50)) | ClassId (int) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | abc9119e-91d1-4205-8efe-ee87b7baa71 | 1 |
| def | xyz9119e-91d1-4205-8efe-ee87b7b1111 | 2 |
| efg | 123-456-789 | 1 |
| hij | xyz9119e-91d1-4205-8efe-ee87b7b1111 | 3 |

I want to delete the records from `table1` that matches the following condition in `table2`, and insert the deleted into a different table (that has the same structure as `table1`):

Condition: table1.StudentId = table2.MemberId AND (for that record) table2.ComputerId is a uniqueidentifier AND ClassId = 1;

So in the above example, both the "abc" records will be deleted. Note that there is no primary key in `table1`.

My plan was to SELECT the correct records from `table1`, then put that SELECT in a DELETE, and then OUTPUT the deleted records into a different table (ignore the OUTPUT part in the below code).

My SELECT for the condition works fine and selects those 2 records, but when I put it in a DELETE, it deletes everything in `table1`.

My SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM table2 B
                WHERE A.StudentId = B.MemberId
                AND TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, B.ComputerId) IS NULL AND ClassId <> 1)
```

My DELETE:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 A
               WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM table2 B
                WHERE A.StudentId = B.MemberId
                AND TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, B.ComputerId) IS NULL AND ClassId <> 1)
)

OUTPUT DELETED.*
INTO <table to insert into>;
```

Comment: What's `ECRehosting_temp`?

Comment: Well, your delete command is just - if a record exists (any record at all) ... then delete everything. Your exists clause returns True so this just becomes DELETE WHERE True

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. Ok, so how do I delete only results of the SELECT then?

Comment: You need to correlate the subquery, @ZuziMufu .

Comment: Yes, there needs to be some connection to ECRehosting_temp to determine which specific rows to delete.

Comment: Sorry, it's Table1. Updated the delete

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```sql
DELETE a
-- SELECT *
FROM table1 A
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table2 B
    WHERE A.StudentId = B.MemberId
    AND TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, B.ComputerId) IS NULL 
    AND ClassId <> 1
)
```

And probably would be better to use `join` instead of `where exists` like:

```sql
DELETE a
-- SELECT *
FROM table1 A
JOIN table2 B
on A.StudentId = B.MemberId
where TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, B.ComputerId) IS NULL 
AND ClassId <> 1
```

You can find more [here on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282993/how-does-sql-server-process-delete-where-exists-select-1-from-table).

Answer (score 0):

This may also make sense to you:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE StudentId IN
(
  SELECT memberId FROM table2 WHERE 
    TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ComputerId) IS NULL AND ClassId <> 1
) 
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO <table to insert into>;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).